# How to hide/show title bar using Carbon

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, title

How to hide/show title bar using Carbon in Mac?

Comment: Why Carbon? It's best to use Cocoa these days...

Answer (score 0):

See HIWindowChangeAttributes and the header comments about it in MacWindows.h.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [this technique](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html) to hide/show title bar:

```
OSStatus SetSystemUIMode( SystemUIMode inMode, SystemUIOptions inOptions);
```

I believe you need to use `kUIModeAllHidden` or `kUIModeContentHidden` with some other `UIOptions` as per your requirement.